# Git and Beanstalk

Tags: git, synchronization, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, beanstalk-svn

I'm experimenting with Git... I've found Beanstalkapp suits my needs.

I've created individual repositories for EACH client on Beanstalk and then pushed all the files from a machine at work.

I've created repositories for each client and my Beanstalk account now looks like this:

```
Client One (repository)<br>
--a load of files and folders<br>
Client Two (repository)<br>
--a load of files and folders<br>
Client Three (repository)<br>
--a load of files and folders
```

...etc

This mirrors the folder structure I established the commit from on another machine

```
**GIT(root)**
  Client One (repository)
    --a load of files and folders
  Client Two (repository)
    --a load of files and folders
  Client Three (repository)
    --a load of files and folders
```

I now need to replicate this on a new machine!

How do I 'pull' the files down (git) and mirror the structure I have on the other machine??  I guess I'm looking for synchronization here?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should make each of your Beanstalk client a **[git submodule](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule)**.
You simply declare:

- a git repo per client
- a git repo in the parent directory of all your current clients, and reference each of the git repos for the clients as submodules.

You can then clone the parent repo, and get back all your clients within it.
([additional cloning might be necessary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules))

Comment: Thanks for this.  I got there in the end. :)