# Git get changes between hash A and B to working directory

Tags: git, diff

Some changes were made in git between hash A and hash B (the branch latest is in Z - thousands of commits later). I'd like to have the HEAD (my local one) point to hash A and have in my working directory all changes that were made between A and B.

Why? Because git diff is inconvenient and I'd rather work with the diff tool my IDE (IntelliJ IDEA) has. But for this I need to convince the IDE that I have changed files - hence the request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found a way:

```
git checkout <hash A>
git diff –patch <hash A> <hash B> > patch.patch
patch –p1 –N < patch.patch
```

A coworker also told me that I could've used

```
git checkout <hash A>
git merge --squash <hash B>
```

instead - but I didn't test it yet.

Comment: I thought --squash had to do with combining multiple commits into a single one? That's doesn't exactly seem to have the same intention.

Comment: I actually wanted these squashed - same as if getting and applying a patch file for the diff between the two revisions.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I use git merge --squash all the time, but I usually squash changes between branches (not commits), and I never attempt to squash while having checked out anything other than HEAD. Just to avoid confusion, I like break out both the commit to be squashed and the commit to squash into out to their own branches.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

- `git clone` your local repo and reset it to `hashB` (see "[Git clone particular version of remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555107/git-clone-particular-version-of-remote-repository)")
- `git reset hashA` within your local repo
- empty its content and replace it: Git Plugin within IDEA will detect all the files added, missing or modified compared to current `HEAD`.