# Open specific version of Git repo in explorer

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

Is there a way to open a version of a Git repository within Windows explorer?

I only see the current state in my explorer but I want to see a specific version. There must be a way with Git.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Revert to previous Git commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/revert-to-previous-git-commit)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would simply to checkout the version (SHA1) you ant to see of that repo:

```
git checkout SHA1
```

Note that would leave the repo in a [detached-HEAD mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309).

If you are working in that repo and want to compare it to an older version, you can clone that repo to another folder, and [reset it at that SHA1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555202/6309):

```
git clone myRepo 
cd myRepo
git reset --hard <SHA1>
```