# android studio - Get a particular version of a Git remote repository

Tags: android, git

I am working with the source of the CyanogenMod camera app that is found [here](https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_Camera2). Now I need to pull a particular version of a revision into Android Studio.

I know after reading this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3555107/4801219) it can be easily done with Git directly, but is there any way to do the same thing within Android Studio that uses Git.

The particular revision that I am wanting to work with has a commit id of -:

```
revision="1855d084de62890057705c05ea57a2d36045532d"
```

Is there any way that I can get exact same revision from within Android Studio without using Git from the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a much longer way to do it, but you may do it if you like. Go to whatever the Repo is, make a new branch with the version you wanted to use, take note of the git url.

In Android Studio, go to VCS Menu close to the end of the top menu, then go down the hierarchy like so:

VCS >> Refresh File Status... wait for about 5 secs. Then do this:

VCS >> Git >> Branches >> Remote Branches

Under the Remote Branches, you should see the branch you made
**origin\"whatever the name"**

Keep in mind that you will first have to fork the repo to your own acct (I dunno if you can do it on the users acct)

Comment: No but what I wanted to use the hash to clone it ?