# Cannot import name 'faster_rcnn_pnas_feature_extractor'

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

I have installed the newest tensorflow version 1.7.
I have also added slim and models to my env variables. 
But I see this error when I try to run - model_builder_test.py

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I bypassed it by reversing the repository back to an earlier version. I tried the one committed on 2018-03-30 (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commits/master?after=5be198eca885fd967426ad5551c8374f1c3e889e+139)

On how to reset git repo: [Git clone particular version of remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555107/git-clone-particular-version-of-remote-repository/18037563)