# Asp.Net Mvc 4 Source code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Is the source for MVC4 available? I've searched on codeplex and all the usual places but don't seem to be able to find? Do MS keep it under wraps until the very end? Why would they do that?

Comment: they usually release beta code for things like orchard etc no?

Comment: Does that mean MVC 3 is an open source?

Comment: Orchard is an open-source project.

Comment: it's open in that you can download and check it out - they don't allow the community to submit pull requests or anything like that though. not sure why anyone would down vote this but it's a free internet i guess.

Comment: It's a shame as I'm itching to get to the nuts and bolts...

Comment: If you can't wait, there's a bunch of [tools](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2425973/64096) that allow you to peek at the source code for any .NET assembly.

Comment: Yeah - aware of them - had to unpick the sharepoint web parts DLLs using one years ago. Think I'll wait for the source :)

Comment: Many of the .NET components have their reference source available here http://referencesource.microsoft.com/netframework.aspx

Answer (score 47, accepted):

They have released the source code and it's available [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: just to update everyone - (and merely pulling the link from the page linked here) - all future code will apparently be released here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/

Comment: @AndrasZoltan - Thanks Andras, will help me very much ! :)

Comment: I can see as per Andras Zoltans link where it is hosted but I can't for the life of me work out how to get MVC 4's code.  Just the latest nightly build?

Comment: @ChrisNevill - It wasn't obvious to me either, but if you go to the downloads section and select "v4.0 RTM", it references a specific change set in the git repo (89b9166ca722).

Comment: Using specific change set you can use this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14091182/1027198 instructions to get proper version.

Comment: Microsoft really needs to learn how to use this new-fangled "tagging" thing.

Comment: Do the git tags use different numbering than the releases? The commit for release v4.0 RTM is tagged in git as v2.0, which is confusing.

Comment: Was wondering how these compare; [aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) and [github ASP NET MVC](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/AuthorizeAttribute.cs) -- is it the difference between MVC4 and MVC3 respectively?