# How to git clone a non-branch, non-tag ref, e.g. Github's magic pull/NN/merge refs

Tags: git, github

Github has [magic refs](https://help.github.com/articles/checking-out-pull-requests-locally/) called pull/*NN*/head, pull/*NN*/merge.

I want to understand what's keeping something like this from working:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/cben/sandbox --branch pull/7/merge
Cloning into 'sandbox'...
fatal: Remote branch pull/7/merge not found in upstream origin
```

This is probably because these refs are neither under `refs/branches` nor `refs/tags` (git clone `--branch` docs say it can also take a tag):

```
$ git ls-remote https://github.com/cben/sandbox
71bea916dee6a03221443cc15c254edc97ff8d42    HEAD
e2f53347112b66ceba2986339c66244cd4458209    refs/heads/branch-to-remain-unmerged
71bea916dee6a03221443cc15c254edc97ff8d42    refs/heads/gh-pages
a34f5181eb779bb6728725f0b21fd9bc78c0d0a8    refs/heads/master
6a23126f508a59c006163aa7fee2dbb7b12d871e    refs/heads/prefixed-header
8ce1ef94fa1e8bf0456aac5368edf0ccdf2c2f3a    refs/heads/test-push-from-c9
6a23126f508a59c006163aa7fee2dbb7b12d871e    refs/pull/6/head
e2f53347112b66ceba2986339c66244cd4458209    refs/pull/7/head
a18487b006434d4f83a6738c1031a80d845bb303    refs/pull/7/merge
71bea916dee6a03221443cc15c254edc97ff8d42    refs/tags/a-tag
```

Is another way to make `git clone` checkout an arbitrary ref (preferably in `--single-branch` / `--depth 1` mode)?

- I know I could clone another branch/tag, fetch this ref and checkout FETCH_HEAD.  I can even use empty git repo technique from https://stackoverflow.com/a/4146786/239657 to avoid downloading anything else:

  ```
  $ git init
  $ git remote add origin https://github.com/cben/sandbox
  $ git fetch origin pull/7/merge --depth 1
  $ git checkout --detach FETCH_HEAD
  ```

  but my motivation is not just achieving the clone — it's figuring out if I can coax tools like npm and Bundler that accept git url branch into using a pull/NN/merge ref directly.

  - UPDATE: bundler accepts `:ref => "refs/pull/232/merge"`! It has [special handling](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/blob/v1.16.1/lib/bundler/source/git/git_proxy.rb#L95) if ref starts with `ref/` — an extra `git fetch` and later in same file `reset --hard` to the desired revision.

Comment: If spelling out the reference (`git clone -b refs/pull/7/merge`) doesn't work—and I suspect it doesn't—you'll have to either build `git clone` out of its primitives (clone = mkdir + git init + git remote add + git fetch + git checkout, more or less), or clone first, then fetch the specific ref, then check it out as a detached HEAD.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43759576/239657 shows that git clone does support an arbitrary refspec! Combined with https://gist.github.com/piscisaureus/3342247, I tried `git clone --config remote.origin.fetch=refs/pull/7/merge:pr-7 https://github.com/cben/sandbox` — close, but I still need to `git fetch` to actually get it fetched, unless I use `--mirror` but that implies bare, nothing is checked out.  Plus I can only add refspecs, so all branches are downloaded?

Comment: `-b refs/pull/7/merge` doesn't work.  `git clone -vv` is helpful to see what heads it requests.  https://git.seveas.net/the-meaning-of-refs-and-refspecs.html is excellent tour of refs and refspecs but didn't help much here.

Comment: Yes, so it looks like you'll need to have some sort of wrapper around / instead-of a direct `git clone`.