# Is there a way to revert the deletion of Bitbucket commits?

Tags: git, bitbucket

Someone on the team has deleted all the commits (except the first one) from the GIT repository (we use Bitbucket).

[image]

Is there anything I can do to get these commits back?
I don't have a local copy of the repo.

Comment: Does anyone  in the team has a local copy of a repository? (even in a state after comment deletion?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover unreferenced commits from remote git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21962653/recover-unreferenced-commits-from-remote-git-repository)

Comment: @Basilevs We only have a deployed version of the code that is several commits behind. We don't have a local copy of the GIT repository.