Reverting master to a few commits back
I want to revert a few commits I pushed from master to master.
Total novice here. I have a Github repository where I have edited a bunch of codes in the past few weeks. I edited codes on the Github web as I'm not really familiar with terminal. I had cloned the repo on my local laptop.
Today for some reason I wanted to add a file in a new directory via terminal so I git pulled the master first and added the directory and file and pushed it to the master. This is where I ruined everything. I didn't notice that I had been on master branch (on my laptop). So I got this error:
To github.com:[my_directory]/[my_repository]
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)


I forced the push with git push --force-with-lease and I succeeded without knowing what I had done.
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
To github.com:[my_directory]/[my_repository]
 + ab8d110...72204c4 master -> master (forced update)

At this point I was expecting to see changes on my github repo but I didn't. So after googling I decided to push it as the first commit.
git commit -m 'first commit'
[master e0a20bf] first commit
 1 file changed, 63 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 _obsolete/projects.md

followed by
git push origin master
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/[my_directory]/.ssh/id_ed25519':
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 798 bytes | 798.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object.
To github.com:[my_directory]/[my_repository]
   72204c4..e0a20bf  master -> master

It was then that I realized the GitHub repo had been updated with the new _obsolete/projects.md, but the code edits that I had made in the other files have been overwritten by whatever I pushed to master. Devastated, I tried various things:
git reset --hard ed25519
git revert e0a20bf
And nothing seemed to work. I totally panicked, and I went ahead and cloned the repo again to my laptop, and now when I do git log, I don't see a thing.
All I want to do is simple, just going back to a few commits back to the red commit. The blues are where I made stupid push commits via the terminal. This is the image from my github repo activity page
Please help!

Branch out from the prev commit you want to restore and then create an MR based on it. I'd recommend staying away from all sorts of resets specially the hard one and rebasing  until you gain enough confidence with git

After I panic-cloned my repo I no longer see any previous commit history when I do "git log". Error says "fatal: Unable to read current working directory: Operation not permitted". What should I do?

Most times master branch is protected against direct modification. If you still managed to break through try finding old code if it's a newcrepo there's hopefully not much to lose. Only advice I can give sorry.

My master branch hasn't been protected. I guess there isn't much to do to salvage edits at this point... Thanks though

When you cloned the new repo, did you delete the old one? The easiest way (but not the only way) to access the commits is to use the old one.

Sigh I deleted it. I don't know what I tinkered with, but now I see the git history "commit e0a20bff1662c17c81f1824ddbfd87ce6e2a2aee (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)" This is the commit I want to undo. Should I do "git revert"?

The force push and deleting and recloning might make this unsalvagable. However, you can provide more diagnostic info to help people provide suggestions by running these commands in the terminal in your repo (make sure you are convinced they are safe to run): 1: git log --graph --decorate --oneline --all 2: git reflog 3: update your question to provide the output of each

https://stackoverflow.com/a/78164353/707111

@Ry - nice find - I was looking for a way to create a branch on an arbitrary commit hash via the Github Web UI (I'm mostly a Gitlab user), but couldn't find one (I only have free private repos on Github).

Thanks all - I couldn't seem to get anything working, so I am writing codes all again on a local branch. Learning it the hard way!
