# Where can I find MVC 4 RTM Source Code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I couldn't find the source code for MVC 4 RTM. So far what I've found is the latest version which is MVC 5. Can anyone help me to provide the location on the web? Thanks.

http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Go to the [v4.0 RTM page](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/releases/view/85150)
- Click on Change Set: [89b9166ca722](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/89b9166ca722)
- Clone this specific change set. ([instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset/14091182#14091182))