# get selected project version by tag

Tags: git

i have local repository, which has two version:

```
$git tag
v1.0.0
v1.0.4
```

in v.0.0 is only initial reposity, with two files:

`aa.txt` - content:

*it's my first file*

`bb.txt` - content:
*it's my second file*

```
$git commit -m 'first commit'
$git push
(...)
```

next time i added new file, names: `cc.txt`, which has content:

*it's file for next version*

```
$git commit -m 'next commit'
$git push
(...)
```

now i want to get pull, but not latest version, only version: **v1.0.0**

what's way?

Answer (score 1):

just use the tag name:

```
git checkout v1.0.0
```

see the [manual for checkout command](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html)

Comment: thanks, but it's not the answer to my question. Other situation: if first version has 1 mb, second vs has 2 GB, then by your way's to download whole project and select the first version?

Comment: @W92 , well, no traffic is consumed when you do the checkout - you have to fetch/pull to get other people's commits. If you do the commits yourself or you've already done the fetch/pull, they are already on your hard drive. If you want to fetch to a specific revision only, then check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3489576/1990682

Answer (score 0):

One way is on webside:

click the selected button:
[image]

`select tags, select your interested tag/version`
and the next step's to **Download.zip**