# Installation issues with iron-router (newest) on Windows 7 x64 (Meteor 0.8.3)

Tags: javascript, windows, meteor, iron-router

I'm attempting to install (via cloned repository) 'iron-router' for my Meteor project in Windows 7.

( Repo:  https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router )

The output is the following:

```
While building package `iron-router`:
error: no such package: 'reactive-dict@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'deps@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'underscore@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'ejson@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'jquery@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'ui@1.0.0'
error: no such package: 'iron'
error: no such package: 'cmather'
error: no such package: 'webapp@1.0.0'
```

Anyway, these are all stock packages that seem to be in %LOCALAPPDATA%/.meteor/packages, because I checked to make sure all the directories were there.

Any thoughts?   I've been developing in Linux for a while now, but I figured if I could get things working in Windows it would be nice if I were too lazy to bother with rebooting (dual-boot environment) after gaming, etc.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changelog specifies that iron:router@0.9.0 just came out on 2014-08-12.

https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/blob/devel/History.md

The latest version of iron:router has been updated to use the new package system which can only be used with meteor 0.9 release candidates.

From your error log, I can tell the iron-router version you cloned from the repo is actually the latest designed for the new package system (deps@1.0.0 used to be just deps without version number) and it complains that it can't find the meteor core packages it depends on, because you're probably running meteor 0.8.3 instead of 0.9-rc?.

What you need to do is fetch iron-router v0.8.2 from the git repo, the commit sha1 is `05415a8891ea87a00fb1e2388585f2ca5a38e0da`

Cloning a git repo from a specific commit hash is a different topic, here is a SO answer to get you started : [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: That would explain it.   I'm sort of new to Meteor and that didn't occur to me at all.  I'll test it right now and see what happens.   Thanks a lot!