# How do I obtain the sources for a specific linux kernel version without cloning the full repository?

Tags: git

Following answers from there:  [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

It seems I can obtain a specific release of the kernel source.
But not being familiar with the way the git repository for the kernel is organized, how do I do that?

I do know this URL is where I would clone the linux kernel from.
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git

But how do I obtain the sha1 for a specific release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the github mirror listed under Linus Torvalds' account:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/releases

That lists the SHA1's of all the releases alongside their version numbers. You could clone from those SHA1's as you describe, or you can just download tarballs if you want.

Comment: Tarball would be even better.  I need the sources to compile up specific modules.