# How to make git accept a URL?

Tags: git

I'm trying to perform the equivalent of a Subversion checkout to a revision. In SVN, this is one step. According to [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3489173) I am supposed to be able to `git remote add origin url://to/source/repository`:

```
# git remote add git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
usage: git remote add [<options>] <name> <url>

    -f, --fetch           fetch the remote branches
    ...
```

Here's the information I have to work with:

```
Could you try whether applying the patch I pointed at (e0fd7c47bd) on the 7.10
branch fixes the internal error?
```

I'm guessing he means GDB's Git, and the revision hash is e0fd7c47bd.

How do I make Git accept the URL provided by the project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to name the remote, so you could do:

`git remote add sourceware git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git`

Comment: Thanks. Yet another error when adding a name like *`xxx`* just to satisfy this tool. Its not worth trying to figure out. I asked them to close the bug report. Another +1 to Git, which took a completely simple task and made it a complete waste of time.

Comment: @jww you've gone an over-complex route to do something very simple, bit inappropriate to blame the tool =).

Comment: @AD7six - they (the Binutil/GDB folks), want a specific patch tested - `e0fd7c47bd`. Under Subverions, I would do a simple one liner: `svn co -r e0fd7c47bd https:////sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb`. We can't go that in Git, which chooses to make it a multistep process and add additional useless requirements, like names.

Comment: You could just download the patch and use `git apply`.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to perform the equivalent of a Subversion checkout to a revision

This is much simpler than the question implies. It's two steps:

```
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/binutils-gdb.git
$ cd binutils-gdb
$ git checkout 7.10
```

Unless there is a problem doing the above, nothing else is required.