# git: Guarantee no binaries are added to commit if they are not handled by git-fat

Tags: git

I am using git-fat with git to handle large binary files.  The problem I am trying to solve is to prevent large binaries being added to local commits IF they are not going to be handled by git-fat.

My approach is to update the pre-commit to block all binary files and only allow files IF:

- the `git fat init` was ran
- the .gitfat file exists and has the rsync configured
- run `git check-attr filter` on the file to verify `filter: fat` is in the output

Am I missing a trick with this? What is a good way to solve this problem with `git` and `git-fat`

For example, Is there anything I can do with the .git/fat/objects to determine that git-fat handled the file when `git add` was called on the binary file?

Comment: What is the particular failure with your current approach?

Comment: @Brannon I would say my proposed solution is heuristic.  I am not looking at git-fat objects etc.. to determine if they binary has been handled by git-fat.  I am basically saying, if these conditions are true, your binary should be handled by git-fat

Answer (score 3):

> Am I missing a trick with this?

It is best to add a restriction on the server side, which will limit/block the size of a push, preventing any large binary that might have fall through the cracks to go through.

To detect if [`git fat init`](https://github.com/jedbrown/git-fat/blob/e1733b1c7c4169d0a1d31cb76f168fb0880176c0/git-fat#L494-L500) was executed, you can simply query the value of `git config filter.fat.clean` and `git config filter.fat.smudge`.

git-fat is interesting in that it does not require any special feature/support on the Git hosting server itself: the storage/replacement of large files is handle by the local filters.

A more recent version of that same file management is **[git lfs](https://git-lfs.github.com/)**, which also operates through Git filters.

Of course, the ultimate solution, which does not require filters and is fully automated is [VFS for Git](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549508/6309), the [Git Virtual Filesystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_Virtual_File_System) developed by Microsoft, and slowly being merged back to Git itself. But it does require a Git repo hosting server which supports that capability.

---

The OP adds:

> Is there anything I can do with the .git/fat/objects to determine that git-fat handled the file when git add was called on the file?

The command [git fat verify](http://cmd_verify) does check each object: it could be tweaked to look a specific file, and check its sha1 between itself and the `catalog_objects`.

Comment: I agree on the server side - but the requirement is to catch it before the commit.  As an aside, the only way I can see of catching it on the server side is in a pre-push hook.  But that's for another day/conversation

Comment: Is there anything I can do with the .git/fat/objects to determine that git-fat handled the file when git add was called on the file?