# TFS to Azure DevOps Migration

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

I am undergoing the process of going from a very old TFS to Azure DevOps.  There is a consideration whether to use TFVC or GIT.  I used the git tfs deep clone feature to create a repo and it was about 3 GB.  Does that mean the repo is too large to use as a git repo?  If I cannot logically break it into smaller repos, does this mean I have to continue using TFVC instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> does this mean I have to continue using TFVC instead?

Not necessarily, you have a few options:

- use [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/) on your Azure server, as detailed by Microsoft in "[Manage and store large files in Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-large-files?view=vsts#use-git-large-file-storage-lfs)"
- use an intermediate server with [VFS for Git active](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52549508/6309), which would then allow you to work with Git repos of multiple hundreds of GB(!).

Comment: An in fact _git itself_ without any modifications may be just fine here.  My repository (the Azure DevOps repo) is about 3 GB and we're reasonably happy with it without VFS for Git.

Comment: @EdwardThomson That means... a git status (mentioned in https://www.gvfs.io/) is not too long? By the way, didn't you say  in a recent podcast you had to change www.gvfs.io? (to something like vfs4g.io)