# clone git repo at specfic commit

Tags: git

As part of our current workflow we pre-clone certain git repos into user homedirs at the time of creation. However, as these repositories grow and user count increases the disk usage has become more and more problematic.

I am attacking this on two fronts:

1. Existing repos with no changed files get `git reset --hard $first_commit` which reverts them to a much tinier initial state. The usual `git pull` on login brings them up to current as always.
2. New users get repos that start at `$initial commit` and can get brought up to current via `git pull`.

While I've come up with a solution for #1 and submitted it for review I'm having trouble coming up with a solution for #2 that doesn't incur a lot of IO overhead.

The simple solution would just be:

```
git clone /opt/git/app.git /home/user/app && \
git -C /home/user/app reset --hard $first_commit
```

However, checking out the full working tree only to delete it incurs a lot of extra IO, which is a valid concern when a new application server is created along with all of the requisite users.

I've tried the following based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3489576/1064767), but the resulting repo isn't properly set up to pull from `origin/master`:

```
git init /home/user/app
git -C /home/user/app remote add origin /opt/git/app.git
git -C /home/user/app fetch origin $first_commit
```

It doesn't seem to have any branch set at all somehow, and the following is missing from `.git/config`:

```
[branch "master"]
        remote = origin
        merge = refs/heads/master
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you don't need any of the git history, would building a binary of your project and simply downloading that work?

Comment: @AndyRay nope. This is a multi-developer environment with a bit of a janky workflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git branch --set-upstream-to` to set `master`’s upstream:

```
git init
git remote add origin /opt/git/app.git
git fetch origin
git reset --hard "$first_commit"
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```