# Download commit using git clone

Tags: git, download, commit, git-clone

With the `git clone` command and arguments `--depth/--branch`, you can download the last commit of a specific repository branch, but how to download a specific commit using its hash?

**P.S.** The use of `git clone` and `git checkout hash` is not suitable, because in that case necessary to make a clone of the entire repository.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: If you don't want to use `git clone` nor `git checkout hash` what do you mean by "download specific commit"? Does it mean *get full code on specific state* or *get only diff between specific commit and previous one* or something else?

Comment: @DamienMATHIEU In the variant that you proposed, you also use the method that downloads the entire repository

Comment: @running.t This means that I'm getting the full code of a specific commit and nothing more, no history of the repository commits.

Comment: Apart from using the shallow clone which you've already suggested, the only other way i can think of downloading a specific commit is by going to github and navigating to the particular commit you are after and then just downloading the files raw - that way you are not downloading the full repo history. but then again, you're not actually downloading the repository but a file. i'd simply clone the repository and then checkout the particular hash you are after and do the work. i can't see a reason to do otherwise because computers these days can handle the memory

Answer (score 0):

If the repo is in github, you can navigate to the tree view of the repo at `https://github.com/<repo_name>/tree/<commit_sha>`

Then clicking on the Download ZIP button on the right-hand navigation bar will download the repo up to the specified commit.

Comment: I know this way, it's not suitable because it's not only downloading github

Comment: could try `git clone https://github.com/<repo_name>/tree/<commit_sha>` or you could make a branch that is set to the desire commit and then clone the branch.