# is it possible to git clone from a specific commit point

Tags: git

**NOTE**: there is an edit to this question below

I have used `git clone ssh://etc` before to pull a remote repository

Is there a way to clone that repository from a specific commit point?

I'm wanting to pull only what happened on `master` say from 1 year ago. The repo is 14 years old and huge.

If this is not possible, is there a way to clone the repo, and then locally compact everything (including all indexes and so forth) into a single "pseudo" commit as if it was the initial code commit?  Thanks.

**Edits:**

The [accepted answer found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset) does not work in this case.  The process only pulls down a repo of the same size, and the entire history is still available (and takes up space).

```
owilliams@OWILLIAMS010451 ~ % du -sh xms_v*                                                                                                                                                                                3:32:56
1.6G    xms_v3
1.6G    xms_v3_ObjectExplorer
1.4G    xms_v3_shallow           <-- no change
```

Not shown but if I move the `.git` folder out of the repo, the size is only 524M.

Here is what it looks like in SourceTree:
[image]

What I am wanting is to see a single commit with a  matching the remote, and what I would a assume as a "pseudo" squashed commit prior to that, as if that was my first code commit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to clone git repository with specific revision/changeset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3489173/how-to-clone-git-repository-with-specific-revision-changeset)

Comment: [`git clone --shallow-since=<date>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---shallow-sinceltdategt)

Comment: Alas, `fatal: Server does not support --shallow-since` :(. But this would be ideal

Comment: I have also edited my answer with the results of the linked suggested answer.  So far this is not a solution

Comment: what about [`git clone --depth=1 --single-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt)