# git submodules with only 1 directory?

Tags: git

i need something like git submodules, but the submodule have to be a directory of another project, rather than the entire project.

For example

The Submodule has:

```
somedir
   files
   dirs
someotherdir
   files
   dirs
thewanteddir
   files
   dir
```

I want to link `thewanteddir` with another project

Is there anything that works like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `somedir`, `someotherdir` and `thewanteddir` are already part of one repo, then you cannot directly see just `thewanteddir` (At best you would the '`theSubmoduleRootDir/thewanteddir`' anyway)
(And [shallow clone submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules) wouldn't isolate just one subdirectory)

The cleanest solution (but not the easiest one) would be to [split that submodule repo in two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359424/detach-subdirectory-into-separate-git-repository), and make thewanteddir its own repo (which you can then add as a submodule)

Comment: Note: partial clone by filepath is not possible with Git: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586824/partial-clone-with-git-and-mercurial/2587244#2587244

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`git-subtree`](https://github.com/apenwarr/git-subtree/) to split off a branch that just has the history of the `thewanteddir` subdirectory, and then set that commit to be the submodule version.  (You'd need to keep using `git-subtree` to update the submodule, and merge back in changes.)