# Shallow depth git submodule update or clone

Tags: git, git-submodules

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Git shallow submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules)

Starting Git 1.6.5+ git clone has a `--recursive` option that also clones submodules, recursively.

The submodules in our project are quite large (lots of history) and sometimes take a long time to clone which can be saved by the `--depth 1` option.

Is there some way to shallow clone (`--depth 1`) these submodules recursively?

Comment: nice question, did you find any answer?

Comment: no, guess only way to do this is a customized script.