# Download git submodules for tarball

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

Is it possible to download submodules for a repository with only the working directory?

If I download a tarball of a repository from GitHub, that is equivalent to a shallow clone without the `.git` folder, is it at all possible to "download" the submodules into the working directory?

I tried `git init && git submodule update --init`, but this neither initializes nor does it update the submodules. The `.gitmodules` file is in the current directory.

**Update**: Some more background on the question: We'd like to use tarballs for checking out repositories at [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.org), but several people use git submodules. "Don't use Git submodules" would therefore not be a good answer, but the answer doesn't really have to be something maintainable either. I just want a folder that has the code checked out and with the submodules initialized, there's no need for anything that allows me to pull down more changes later.

Comment: Why wouldn't a `git submodule update --init --recursive --force` be working? It should load those submodules (but with their full history). Note that [git1.8.4 will add a --depth for shallow submodule clone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17692710/6309).

Comment: @VonC If only I knew. That command does nothing at all for me. No errors, but it returns "instantly" without any output.

Comment: What is the content of your `.gitmodules` file? And what version of git are you using?

Comment: Here's an example with the commands to download the tarball and all: https://gist.github.com/henrikhodne/49bb2c11d2fe25b31089

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining a wget/tar approach, with a `git init` won't help you initialize submodules:

Everything is untracked after the `git init`.

You need to add and commit everything, *before*:

```
git submodule update --init --recursive --force
```

That `git submodule` command will then "work", but create only empty directories.
That is because the tar file didn't include the **[special entries (160000)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309)** created by a [`git submodule add`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2227598/6309).

You need to re-declare those submodules:

```
C:\prog\git\ReactiveCocoa-2.0-development>git submodule add --name xcconfigs https://github.com/jspahrsummers/xcconfigs.git external\xcconfigs
Cloning into 'external\xcconfigs'...
remote: Counting objects: 312, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (229/229), done.
Receal 312 (delta 87), reused 306 (delta 82)
Receiving objects: 100% (312/312), 64.51 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (87/87), done.
```

Comment: This still doesn't work for me. I'm using the same commands as the gist in the comment above, with `git add -A . && git commit -m "commit everything"` immediately after `git init`.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like we have to parse the `.gitmodules` file then and readd everything. I was hoping for something slightly more automated, but I guess it will work.