# Restore shallow clone repository branches tags and history

Tags: git

I'm taking over a project from source code that is a shallow clone. The .git/config file shows:

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = git@bitbucket.org:[account]/[project].git
    fetch = +refs/tags/v1.2.0:refs/tags/v1.2.0
```

Is there any way to restore the repository from the info contained in the .git directory so I can import it into a new repository with branches, tags and history intact? I have no access to the origin so I can't re-clone or fetch or anything like that.

The .git directory is chock full of data, so it's not like, for example, a fresh git init:

```
$ ls -lsa .git
total 416
  0 drwxr-xr-x@ 15 user  staff     480  1 Dec 11:50 .
  0 drwxr-xr-x@ 37 user  staff    1184  1 Dec 11:07 ..
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff      41  1 Dec 11:07 HEAD
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff      41  1 Dec 11:07 ORIG_HEAD
  0 drwxr-xr-x@  2 user  staff      64  1 Dec 11:07 branches
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff     205  1 Dec 11:07 config
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff      73  1 Dec 11:07 description
  0 drwxr-xr-x@ 11 user  staff     352  1 Dec 11:07 hooks
368 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff  185503  1 Dec 11:50 index
  0 drwxr-xr-x@  3 user  staff      96  1 Dec 11:07 info
  0 drwxr-xr-x@  3 user  staff      96  1 Dec 11:07 logs
  0 drwxr-xr-x@  4 user  staff     128  1 Dec 11:07 objects
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff      99  1 Dec 11:07 packed-refs
  0 drwxr-xr-x@  4 user  staff     128  1 Dec 11:07 refs
  8 -rw-r--r--@  1 user  staff     615  1 Dec 11:07 shallow
```

The result of 'git filter-branch -- --all' is the "rewriting" of over 400 commits. It seems like there is some potential here to do what I need, I'm just not sure how to do it.

```
$ git branch -v
* (no branch) 1f8406c Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/develop'

$ git checkout develop
error: pathspec 'develop' did not match any file(s) known to git.

$ git checkout master
error: pathspec 'master' did not match any file(s) known to git.
```

Comment: what do you mean "restore the repository"? Your local repo currently only contains the single remote commit tagged as v1.2.0. HEAD is detached relative to the remote and local repo has a fake root starting from remote tag v1.2.0. Your local repo is equivalent to someone downloading v.1.2.0 zip file from bitbucket, and doing `git init .` after unzipping and adding a remote with the fetch set to what you see (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075972/how-to-update-a-git-shallow-clone)

Comment: I've added further information to the question. Feel free to post an answer, sounds like you're confident in your conclusion.

Comment: are you asking whether there is a way to recover origin repo beyond tag v1.2.0?

Comment: No, that would make no sense.

Comment: then I don't know what you're asking. You should already be able to clone this shallow clone, and it should contain all of the commits made to the shallow clone.

Comment: Added more detail. I'm asking how to get the branches, tags and history from this shallow clone into a new repo. And yes, the history is here in this shallow clone.

Comment: Whomever was committing to the shallow clone did not make any branches, they committed directly to the detached HEAD. Your last commit shows they merged from remote-tracking branch `develop` which is not in the local repo because they did not merge it using `git pull`, they used `git fetch origin develop; git merge; git commit`