# How to fetch/pull changes from shallow branch (--depth 1)

Tags: git, github, mean

I'm working on a MEAN framework project.
[MEAN github repository link](https://github.com/linnovate/mean)

I used following command to clone the MEAN repository as shown in their documentation.

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git
```

I did it few weeks later and now I need to update my local repository from this original repository. Their official repository is 30 commits ahead. So I used following command.

```
git fetch
```

Normally it suppose to fetch all the changes and update my repository. But this time, it did nothing.

Then I used following command.

```
 git fetch --depth 1
```

And then it showed me this.

```
remote: Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
```

Can anyone please tell me how to fetch all the changes from official repository. Here is my forked repository.
https://github.com/chanakaDe/mean

I used following 2 commands also. But no good results.

```
git pull
git pull --depth 1
```

Please help me on this. :-)

Comment: Which branch are you on? `master`?

Answer (score 1):

As stated in [this very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41081908/7598462) to the same question:

> git fetch
>
> git reset --hard origin/master
>
> (git clean -dfx)