# How to specify depth in pull (in TortoiseGit)?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

In TortoiseGit, when cloning a repo with `depth=1`, then on next pull, it still obtains whole past history. How to specify to pull only the changes, which happened after cloning date, and thus, not fetch the whole history before cloning date (which we intentionally skipped by `depth=1`)?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41075972/how-to-update-a-git-shallow-clone

Answer (score 0):

TortoiseGit (as of version 2.12) does not allow to specify a "depth" on fetching or pulling (cf. https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-pull.html).