# Configure depth of git submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, depth

I realize you can set the depth of a submodule manually when updating it, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules), but is it possible to set that automatically, say as an option in the gitconfig? This way I could set it so when updating a submodule it only ever brings down a revision history of depth 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible (for now, mid-2014) through [`git config`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

You could define an alias or a special script to add that parameters, but you can set `depth` natively with git alone.