# Wordpress Git submodule very large disk space

Tags: wordpress, git

I am working on a Wordpress site in a git repository where the Wordpress core is separated out as a submodule.

**UPDATE:**
I am pointing at the latest tag, rather than the master branch.

This has resulted in over 160MB of disk space being used.

The site was first pulled in with `git clone URL .` and then the submodules loaded with `git submodule update --init --recursive` ([taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules#answer-4438292))

The Wordpress git repo is here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress

I assume this has just downloaded all commit messages or something? Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: What environment are you working in, that 160MB is a lot of disk space?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2144406/git-shallow-submodules

Comment: Sebastian I'm using Sublime editor and terminal, @MartinNyolt - thank you, I'll give that a try

Comment: I have added that I am pointing the submodule at a tag (the latest Wordpress release) rather than following the latest commit in the master branch.