# Git 2.8 fails to update submodules

Tags: docker, git-submodules

I am trying to [build gRPC](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/BUILDING.md#unix) inside a docker image, but updating the submodules is failing when using git version 2.8. Specifically this Dockerfile:

```
FROM alpine:3.3
RUN apk update && apk add git
RUN git clone -b 'v1.17.1' --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
RUN git --version
RUN cd grpc && git submodule update --init --depth 1
```

shows `git version 2.8.6` and throws the following error

```
Cloning into '/grpc/third_party/abseil-cpp'...
error: no such remote ref cc4bed2d74f7c8717e31f9579214ab52a9c9c610
```

If I switch to `alpine:3.8` I get `git version 2.18.1` and the build is successful. Is this a bug in the earlier version of git? Is there a workaround?

Notes:

- I'm specifying `--depth 1` because I don't need the commit history.
- I have some unrelated constraints which make it difficult to use a more recent version.

Comment: At `.gitmodules` you should update latest commit id of your sub module at `master` branch.

Comment: This commit id `cc4bed2d74f7c8717e31f9579214ab52a9c9c610` couldn't for access from your main project.

Comment: @QuỳnhNguyễn if that is the problem, why does it work correctly with the newer version of git? btw [the commit id exists](https://github.com/abseil/abseil-cpp/commit/cc4bed2d74f7c8717e31f9579214ab52a9c9c610).

Comment: This may explain the problem: https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-downloader/issues/32#issuecomment-56974091

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in "[How to make shallow git submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17692710/6309)", multiple evolution have been made since Git 2.8.

If available, try and use only one step:

```
git clone -b 'v1.17.1' --recurse-submodule --depth 1 https://github.com/grpc/grpc
```